# How to wrap cents of tier prices in a block?

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I want to change the style of the tier price cents on the product page. To do this, I need them to be rendered on the page in this form:
`10<span>99</span>`

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml
```

This is the template that renders the tier price html for *simple* products. If a simple product has tier prices the template loops through them and outputs the price html

```
foreach ($tierPrices as $index => $price)
```

The template formats the price using using

```
$priceAmountBlock=$block->renderAmount(
    $price['price'],
    [
        'price_id'          => $index,
        'id_suffix'         => '-' . $index,
        'include_container' => true
    ]
)
```

`$priceAmountBlock` is the formatted price with the correct currency symbol wrapped in a *price* span element.

You could try and extend the `renderAmount` method but it's used for all pricing, not just tier prices. You could also modify `$priceAmountBlock` directly in the template to add the extra span elements you want

```
        $decimalSeperator='.';
        $priceFormatted=number_format($price['price']->__toString(), 2, $decimalSeperator, '');
        $priceParts=explode('.',$priceFormatted);
        $priceAmountBlock = $block->renderAmount(
                $price['price'],
                [
                    'price_id'          => $index,
                    'id_suffix'         => '-' . $index,
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_OPTION
                ]
            );
        $priceAmountBlock=str_replace($priceFormatted,'<span class="before-decimal">'.$priceParts[0].'</span>'.$decimalSeperator.'<span class="after-decimal">'.$priceParts[1].'</span>',$priceAmountBlock)
```

If the tier price is **5** This would give you

```
<span class=price>€<span class=before-decimal>5</span>.<span class=after-decimal>00</span></span>
```

[image]

It's a bit of a hack, *but it works!*

Comment: Hello, i get on front end `Buy 6 for 111.11" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper " > 44.11€`

Where did I go wrong?